Is there a way to create multiple list style, use either one when needed?
Figured out how to define multiple list styles but when trying to use them it always defaults to the last defined list style.
For example, I defined bullet list with numID X and then numbered list with numId Y. In my main script, I change the numering property of the text with numID X but it will still apply numbering instead of bullets. If I do not have numered list defined with numId Y, it behaves as expected and adds bullets.
Creating custom number styles as below.
class CustomStyles:
num_ids = {}  # A dictionary to store numbering IDs for different styles

@staticmethod
def initialize_styles(document):
    """
    Define all custom numbering styles and register them in `num_ids`.
    """
    # SRK Bullet List
    level_formats = [
        {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'bullet', 'lvlText': '▪', 'left': '173', 'hanging': '173'},
        {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'bullet', 'lvlText': '\u2013', 'left': '346', 'hanging': '173'},
        {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'bullet', 'lvlText': '▪', 'left': '518', 'hanging': '172'},
        {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'bullet', 'lvlText': '\u2013', 'left': '690', 'hanging': '172'},
        {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'bullet', 'lvlText': '▪', 'left': '861', 'hanging': '171'},
        {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'bullet', 'lvlText': '\u2013', 'left': '1032', 'hanging': '171'}
    ]
    CustomStyles.num_ids['bullet_list'] = CustomStyles.create_bullet_numbering(document, level_formats)

    numbered_list_formats = [
    {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '%1', 'left': '720', 'hanging': '720'},  # Level 0
    {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '%1.%2', 'left': '720', 'hanging': '720'},  # Level 1
    {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '%1.%2.%3', 'left': '720', 'hanging': '720'},  # Level 2
    {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '', 'left': '720', 'hanging': '720'}  # Level 3
    # {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '', 'left': '3600', 'hanging': '720'},  # Level 4
    # {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '', 'left': '4320', 'hanging': '720'},  # Level 5
    # {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '', 'left': '5040', 'hanging': '720'},  # Level 6
    # {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '', 'left': '5760', 'hanging': '720'},  # Level 7
    # {'start': 1, 'numFmt': 'decimal', 'lvlText': '', 'left': '6480', 'hanging': '720'}  # Level 8
    ]

    CustomStyles.num_ids['numbered_list'] = CustomStyles.create_numbered_numbering(document, numbered_list_formats)

@staticmethod
def get_max_abstract_num_id(numbering_elm):
    abstract_num_ids = [
        int(abstract_num.get(qn('w:abstractNumId')))
        for abstract_num in numbering_elm.findall(qn('w:abstractNum'))
    ]
    return max(abstract_num_ids) if abstract_num_ids else -1

@staticmethod
def get_max_num_id(numbering_elm):
    num_ids = [
        int(num.get(qn('w:numId')))
        for num in numbering_elm.findall(qn('w:num'))
    ]
    return max(num_ids) if num_ids else -1

@staticmethod
def create_bullet_numbering(document, level_formats):
    """
    Creates a custom numbering definition in the document.
    """
    numbering_part = document.part.numbering_part
    numbering_elm = numbering_part.element

    # Use class variables for numbering IDs
    max_abstract_num_id = CustomStyles.get_max_abstract_num_id(numbering_elm)
    max_num_id = CustomStyles.get_max_num_id(numbering_elm)
    next_abstract_num_id = max_abstract_num_id + 1000
    next_num_id = max_num_id + 1000

    # Build the abstract numbering definition
    abstract_num = OxmlElement('w:abstractNum')
    abstract_num.set(qn('w:abstractNumId'), str(next_abstract_num_id))

    nsid_value = ''.join(random.choices('0123456789ABCDEF', k=8))
    nsid = OxmlElement('w:nsid')
    nsid.set(qn('w:val'), nsid_value)
    abstract_num.append(nsid)

    multi_level_type = OxmlElement('w:multiLevelType')
    multi_level_type.set(qn('w:val'), 'multilevel')
    abstract_num.append(multi_level_type)

    # Create levels with custom formatting
    for i, fmt in enumerate(level_formats):
        lvl = OxmlElement('w:lvl')
        lvl.set(qn('w:ilvl'), str(i))

        start = OxmlElement('w:start')
        start.set(qn('w:val'), str(fmt.get('start', 1)))
        lvl.append(start)

        numFmt = OxmlElement('w:numFmt')
        numFmt.set(qn('w:val'), fmt.get('numFmt'))
        lvl.append(numFmt)


        lvlText = OxmlElement('w:lvlText')
        lvlText.set(qn('w:val'), fmt.get('lvlText'))
        lvl.append(lvlText)

        suff = OxmlElement('w:suff')
        suff.set(qn('w:val'), 'tab')
        lvl.append(suff)

        lvlJc = OxmlElement('w:lvlJc')
        lvlJc.set(qn('w:val'), 'left')
        lvl.append(lvlJc)

        pPr = OxmlElement('w:pPr')
        ind = OxmlElement('w:ind')
        if fmt.get('left') is not None:
            ind.set(qn('w:left'), fmt['left'])
        if fmt.get('hanging') is not None:
            ind.set(qn('w:hanging'), fmt['hanging'])
        pPr.append(ind)
        lvl.append(pPr)

        # Add custom bullet color
        rPr = OxmlElement('w:rPr')
        color = OxmlElement('w:color')
        color.set(qn('w:val'), 'FF8000')  # Orange color in hex
        rPr.append(color)
        lvl.append(rPr)

        abstract_num.append(lvl)

    # Append the definitions to the numbering part
    numbering_elm.append(abstract_num)

    # Build the num element
    num = OxmlElement('w:num')
    num.set(qn('w:numId'), str(next_num_id))

    abstract_num_id_elm = OxmlElement('w:abstractNumId')
    abstract_num_id_elm.set(qn('w:val'), str(next_abstract_num_id))
    abstract_num_id_elm.set(qn('w:default'), '0')
    num.append(abstract_num_id_elm)


    # Append the abstractNum and num elements to the numbering part
    numbering_elm.append(num)

    return next_num_id

Using another but similar function to create list style with numbering.
In the main script I then change the numID for the paragraph as below.
p = paragraph._p  # Access the XML element of the paragraph
pPr = p.get_or_add_pPr()  # Get or add the paragraph properties element

# Create or get the numbering properties element
numPr = pPr.find(qn('w:numPr'))
if numPr is not None:
    pPr.remove(numPr)
if numPr is None:
    numPr = OxmlElement('w:numPr')

# Create and append the numId element
numId_element = OxmlElement('w:numId')
numId_element.set(qn('w:val'), str(num_id))
numPr.append(numId_element)

# Create and append the ilvl element
ilvl_element = OxmlElement('w:ilvl')
ilvl_element.set(qn('w:val'), str(ilvl))
numPr.append(ilvl_element)

pPr.append(numPr)

Both have list styles have different numIds and I confirmed that in the document.xml it is appending elements as expected with correct and different numIds. In the numbering.xml it has both numering definations with unique numIds.
Has anyone dealt with this before? I am not sure if this is python-docx limitation or I doing something wrong. I would appriciate any help.
